# Woocommerce API (Woo Dashboard github)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm triying the Woo Dashboard example from this [github](https://github.com/shahroznawaz/woo-dashboard/blob/master/index.php) bu

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in [[[[MY FILE URL]]]] Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in [[[[MY FILE URL]]]] on line 33

The code in line 32 and 33 is the following:

```
$sales = $woocommerce->get('reports/sales', $query);
$sale = $sales[0]["total_sales"];
```

I've read many people who had use this github as boilerplate but none one else with this issue

Answer (score 0):

I've change `$sale = $sales[0]["total_sales"];` to `$sale = $sales[0]->total_sales;` and is working now.